# Loop runs n+1 times instead forunnig for n times

Tags: iteration, recurrence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNaY5.png)

was learning the difference between iteration and recurrence one question
why is the loop run n+1 times?

Comment: Please post code as text, not image. And tag your language

Comment: The condition is checked `n+1` times, but the loop body is only executed `n` times.

Comment: Walk through the code in your head (it's not complicated), starting from n=2 to keep it simple

Answer (score 0):

When starting with calculating O notation, it is probably best to work through a small example (such as 3 in your scenario).

`n` being the variable in the picture and `i` the number of iterations.

Condition: `n > 0`

```
n    i
3    1
2    2
1    3
0    -
```

So this would be `O(n)` and would be `O(n+1)` if the condition were `>=` but in either scenario you would simplify it to `O(n)`